# what is the reason behind below condition

Tags: java, operator-keyword

```
class MagicWithOperators{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float  f = 10.2F; 
        double d = 10.2; 
        System.out.println(f==d);
    }
}
```

Output: `false`.

why `10.2f==10.2` is false but `10.0f==10.0` is true?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7392200/4028085

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the value `10.2` cannot be represented exactly, using either `float` or `double` representations.  Both are different approximations to 10.2, which are mathematically not equal.

The reason that it's `true` for `10.0f` and `10.0` is that 10 can be represented exactly in both `float` and `double` representations.

Here are the hexadecimal representations of all the numbers above.

```
41233333          // 10.2f (float, inexact)
4024666666666666  // 10.2  (double, inexact)
4024666660000000  // 10.2f (widened to double, inexact)

41200000          // 10.0f (float, exact)
4024000000000000  // 10.0  (double, exact)
4024000000000000  // 10.0f (widened to double, exact)
```

The conversions are done with `Integer.toHexString(Float.floatToIntBits())` and `Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits)`.