# While loop not exiting

Tags: java, while-loop

New to Java on this end. I'm trying to run a program that rolls two dice and when the total roll between the two die is either 7 or 11 the program will exit. For some reason my while statement is executing over and over again, and I can't figure out why. Any help would be really appreciated. Code is below.

Again, very new to this. Not so much focused on a more efficient way to do this at the very moment, but rather the semantic details of why this is not functioning.

```
// import required packages for the program
// import all classes to be on the safe side
// will be using input/ouput and math, so those imports are needed
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;

// Declare a class, class name Dice chosen
public class Dice
{
// need to use throws IOException because we are dealing with input and output, simple main method will not suffice
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        // declare variables for the two dice, randomize each
        // die can each be rolled for # between 1-6
        double dice1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        double dice2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

        // declare variable for combined roll
        double totalRoll = dice1 + dice2;

        //create loop to determine if totalRoll is a 7 or 11, if not continue rolling
        while ((totalRoll != 7.0) || (totalRoll != 11.0))
            {
            dice1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            dice2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

            totalRoll = dice1 + dice2;

            System.out.println("The roll on die 1 is: " + dice1);
            System.out.println("The roll on die 2 is: " + dice2);
            System.out.println("The total of the two rolls is: " + totalRoll + "\n");

            if ((totalRoll == 7.0) || (totalRoll == 11.0)) 
            {
            System.out.println("You win!");
            }
            }


        /*
        // declare in as a BufferedReader; used to gain input from the user
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        //Simulate tossing of two dice
        */




    }
}
```

Comment: What does `(totalRoll != 7.0) || (totalRoll != 11.0)` mean? Can a number be equal to two values?

Comment: If the total roll is not 7 or 11 then re roll the die until a 7 or 11 is hit

Comment: Why are you using `double`s to represent dice? Think about which values you want them to be able to have.

Comment: I know that they are integers, but representing .0 doesn't really affect the program functionality, does it?

Comment: @Keppil its a real dice :D

Comment: @Zack, if a 7 is rolled the `while` would *still* continue because it's also not equal to 11. `totalRoll == 7.0` but `totalRoll != 11.0`. That satisfies the condition because you're using an `OR`.

Comment: Your || should be && (or just &)

Comment: @DSlomer64 `&` is bitwise AND

Comment: Well, read this: "The && and || operators 'short-circuit', meaning they don't evaluate the right hand side if it isn't necessary. 
The & and | operators, when used as logical operators, always evaluate both sides." I found that and **31 up votes** [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting) among other places. So I just gave that guy another up vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to swap your `OR` for an `AND`. With an `OR`, that `while` statement will always evaluate to true, because a single number can not be both `7` and `11` at the same time (unless it's some brutal quantum computing, but I'll assume it's not).

```
while(totalRoll != 7.0 && totalRoll != 11.0) {
    // Continue.
}
```

***NOTE***: If you are trying to make a quantum dice, then one could argue you'd need to roll the dice an infinite amount of times, given the single di face could equal all numbers simultaneously, so in this context your program is working beautifully... just food for thought.

***Serious NOTE***: Using a `double` to represent a value on a dice is really wasteful. You're reserving a lot more memory than you need to. Use an `int` or even a `byte`, if you wanted to optimize your memory usage.

***Edit in response to comment***

You added the break to your `if` statement; I am assuming. Well, you see, this is different. You're claiming if the number equals one of these numbers. Let me run an example for you.

*When dealing with equality*

The logic in your if statement is fine, because, let's say:

```
double totalRoll = 7.0;

if(totalRoll == 7.0 || totalRoll == 11.0)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

This evaluates to:

```
if(7.0 == 7.0 || 7.0 == 11.0)
{
}
```

Which becomes:

```
if(true || false)
```

And because `TRUE OR X == TRUE`, it becomes:

```
if(true)
```

Likewise, if you set `totalRoll` to `9.0`:

```
if(9.0 == 7.0 || 9.0 == 11.0)
{
}
```

Which becomes.

```
if(false || false)
```

Which finally evaluates to:

```
if(false)
```

So we have proven by demonstration, that this `if statement` can handle input. Let's try out your `while` loop.

*When dealing with inequality*

```
double totalRoll = 7.0;

// We expect this to stop the loop..
while(totalRoll != 7.0 || totalRoll != 11.0)
```

Evaluates to

```
while(7.0 != 7.0 || 7.0 != 11.0)
```

And that evaluates to:

```
while(false || true)
```

Once again, `X OR TRUE == TRUE` so.

```
while(true)
```

Oh dear. So as you can see, the only way this `while` loop will ever break, is if the value of `totalRoll` is both `7.0` and `11.0` at the same time.

*Why the solution works*

We fix it, by swapping the `OR` for an `AND`.

```
double totalRoll = 7.0;

while(7.0 != 7.0 && 7.0 != 11.0)
{
}
```

Evaluates to..

```
while(false && true)
```

And we know that `FALSE AND X == FALSE` so

```
while(false)
```

And the loop breaks. The same will happen with `11.0`, but not with any other number.

Comment: But the while loop seemed to work when I added the break. The or operation seems to get at what I'm trying to do though? If a number is not this or it is not this then re-roll.

Comment: I've just added a big ol' demonstration why the `while loop` does not work.

Comment: Very helpful in understanding the logic. Thanks a ton.

Comment: If this answer was most helpful, can you please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an break, right after the System.out.print

```
if ((totalRoll == 7.0) || (totalRoll == 11.0))
    {
        System.out.println("You win!");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: True, but that doesn't really explain why the `while` loop isn't working the way OP expects it to.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would like the `while` statement to be this--it's clearer:

```
   while (!(totalRoll == 7.0 || totalRoll == 11.0))
```

"While it is not true that roll equals 7 or 11..."

Answer (score 0):

Re: @Paranix "& is bitwise"...

Here's a quote from SO:

"The && and || operators **'short-circuit'**, meaning they don't evaluate the right hand side if it isn't necessary. The & and | operators, when used as logical operators, always evaluate both sides."

I found that and **31 up votes** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting) and found similar wording elsewhere. But maybe that quote needs modification, since & *does do* "bitwise and", *period*.

That is, if both operands happen to be boolean, they're integers, either 1 or 0, so bitwise stuff applies.

1&1 is true (equals 1); 1&0, 0&1, 0&0 are false (equal 0).

The statement below prints 0,0,0,1:

```
System.out.println((1&0) + "," + (0&1) + "," + (0&0) + "," + (1&1));
```

You get error if using (1 && 0) since && requires boolean operands.

In any event, the modified dice code works correctly with either & or &&.

I've read that && is definitely required if there's any chance the right-hand operand is null, but I can't demonstrate that.

Answer (score -1):

Comparing doubles like that is very problematic; due to the way double values are represented chances are that `totalRoll == 7.0` will not give you true, even if `totalRoll` is exactly 7.0. A better way to compare doubles (if you have to use them) would be something like this:

```
while (Math.abs(totalRoll - 7.0) > 0.0001 && Math.abs(totalRoll - 11.0) > 0.0001) { ... }
```

That way the inaccuracy of saving double values doesn't hurt you as much.

**Edit:** As there have been downvotes, I'll post some more information to back up what I'm saying:

- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is a good article that shows various problems related to floats and doubles
- [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786254/is-it-safe-when-compare-2-float-double-directly-in-java) explains in some detail how to compare two double values safely
- [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is a class in the Java standard library which works for any precision, so its [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) function will be more accurate than the method explained above

Also, the following code prints `false` for me:

```
System.out.println(((7.0 / 100) * 100) == 7.0);
```

If anyone has information that disproves what I'm saying then please tell me about it.

Comment: This is just completely untrue.

Comment: Oh, is it? Is there a great new way of using double values that contradicts this? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html If so, why do we need `BigDecimal`? I'm happy to take my answer back if you have anything that disproves my statement.

Comment: Have you looked at the `double` representation of 7.0?  As a general rule, the `double` type represents smallish integers exactly; so `==` works fine to compare them.  You get into trouble with non-integer values, or with very large integers; but 7.0 is neither.  And as far as disproving your statement goes, I suggest you simply test `(x == 7.0)` for various values of `x` and see for yourself.

Comment: As for `((7.0 / 100) * 100)` - the reason why this isn't exactly `7.0` is that `0.07` can't be represented exactly as a `double`.  So there's an implicit rounding step that happens with the division, and that introduces a small error.  So the problem isn't with 7.0, it's with 0.07.

Comment: @DavidWallace That is, basically, what I said: the representation of doubles is imperfect, so you shouldn't compare doubles with `==`. I wasn't suggesting that the problem in the original post could be solved by switching to a different type of comparison, I was commenting on the danger of comparing doubles with `==`. Mind you, the information about when they are easy to represent and when they aren't is interesting, I didn't know that distinction.

Comment: The dialog between @David Wallace and @blalasaadri needn't cause downvotes. Both make excellent points from which significant learning can occur, whether by newbie or old-bie. I, for one, paid no attention to the use of `double` in a situation that definitely calls for `int`. I figured "leave the code alone as much as possible" rather than give unrequested advice. But I, for one, am glad the last few comments were posted.

Comment: I just bought Ivor Horton's "Beginning Java", a very good book. He addresses "&& vs. &" and "|| vs. |" by calling && and || "conditional and" and "conditional or", respectively, his point being that only conditionally will the right-hand operand be dealt with. I like that. This is also the terminology used at [this Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) .

Comment: @DSlomer64 While this is true, it has nothing to do with my reply; maybe you meant to add it to the original question or to a reply that handles those operators?

Comment: @blala... I didn't intend either of my comments to be criticism of your answer. In fact, I upvoted you on Jan 14 (I just found out as I tried to do so again) and admonished whoever DID downvote you in my comment of that same date (my comment before yesterday's). When I posted my comment yesterday, I wasn't paying attention to where I was sticking it. My intent was to make sure it was noticed in that "conditional and" (... "or") concisely and vividly describes the difference between && and & (|| and |). I will be more aware in the future that position of comments matters.